# Unable to locate package ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Firing up an old netbook (1.6 GHz 2 core Acer, 1 gig memory running Ubuntu 12.04) and find that it has ros-fuerte on it. I wish to remove/uninstall this. I tried sudo apt-get remove ros but I get E: Unable to locate package ros

any ideas? I know its there, locate shows all the files, the workspace is in the home folder, update manager is trying to update files, etc.

regards, Richard

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55537/unable-to-locate-package-ros/) by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That error msg from apt means there's no debian package with the name 'ros'. In your case if you want to remove all ROS fuerte related packages, run:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-*
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on 2013-02-18**:
That did it, thanks.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-02-18**:
@richkappler if this answer is satisfactory, can you click the "check" sign on the left so that people can tell this question is solved?